# Understanding license of extjs library usage

Tags: extjs

Recently started using ExtJS library...but still unclear on it's licensing policy.
I work for a company and maintain internal web applications for reporting etc... utilizing ExtJS library to enhance user experiences.
Web app. is not public since it only runs in intranet. 
Can anybody share a thought...
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have [3 different licence options](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/license/) and the only option that is free is GNU GPL license v3. but if you use that you need to release the source code of the web apps that you develop. so I think you will need a commercial licence.

Comment: yes, that is where i'm still confused, like you said "need to release the source code of the web app". I will not be changing the library itself, only use their API.

Comment: but then you need to pay. the only option if you dont want to pay is to release the source code of your web app even if you only use their API.